# why isn't this child event updating state in parent (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component called customize-charts that includes a Vuetify drawer:

```
<template>
  <v-col>
    <v-btn style="float: right" class="mr-4 mt-2" small @click="toggleCustomize"  v-if="!open">Customize Dashboard</v-btn>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="open"
      temporary
      absolute
      right
      style="width: 25vw"
    >
      <span>draw contents</span>
      <v-divider />
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-col>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Array,
      default () { return [] }
    },
    open: {
      type: Boolean,
      default () { return false }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      draggingItem: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleCustomize () {
      this.$emit('open')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, the boolean that the drawer is listening to is called "open" and it is passed from the parent:

```
  <customize-charts v-if="chartCards.length" :data="chartCards" :open="customizePanel" @updateorder="updateOrder" @toggleshow="toggleShow" @open="customizePanel=!customizePanel"/>
```

The parent also has the following:

```
{
  data () {
    return {
       customizePanel: false,
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that when the custom event `open` is called (@open="customizePanel=!customizePanel"), the drawer opens, but when it closes (user clicks outself of drawer) it does not set `customizePanel` to false.  How can I make this happen?

Comment: Have you tried using `@transitioned` instead of `@click`? Found it [here[(https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/) under 'Events'

Comment: @JesseRezaKhorasanee  I just tried this, and it didn't work.

Comment: I am not able to look in a proper environment but you could try and use the hidden event `@hidden=customizePanel=!customizePanel` ?

Comment: @Maylor  This also didn't work :(

Comment: Are you willing to try putting it in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-basic-example-forked-8xt6e?file=/src/components/Chart.component.vue)? I find that often helps for debugging and allows users to play around with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are using prop `open` with `v-model`. Props are designed as one way data binding only (passing data from parent to child) and you should not modify it's value in child component (if you open browser Dev Tools, I'm sure you will see nice warning from Vue explaining exactly this) as the new value will be overwritten by parent value on next re-render...

just use computed property for `v-model`:

```js
computed: {
  isOpen: {
   get() { return this.open }, // return prop value
   set() { this.$emit('open') } // emit event and change prop value in parent's event handler - new value gets propagated back to child
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, also replaced v-model with `isOpen`.  It seems this causes some sort of recursive call, because the browser freezes up and the drawer doesn't open.